# why is button too wide using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am have an input type button and am using bootstrap but the button shows up very wide on my page and I don't really understand why. I am also using blade and laravel. I use blade to open the form (not sure if that could affect it).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
        <div>
            <select class="col-xs-1" name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in selectOptions" ng-change="change(data.singleSelect)">
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="back" ng-click="upOneLevel()" class="btn btn-default col-xs-11"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I use the same html on my site and on jsfiddle with bootstrap and it looks good, but on my  screen it looks like [image]

The back button is huge. I want it to look like how it does in fiddle like this:
[image]

any ideas?
I am also using jquery and rateit2 if that affects anything.

Also all of the input fields of my form look too wide
[image]

This is after julio's suggestion 
[image]

Comment: try to remove this class "navbar-btn"

Comment: It's working fine for me you should post more relevant code - http://www.bootply.com/JJLVPg7fjF

Comment: @LaljiTadhani thanks, I have tried without navbar-btn. I added that to see if it would help.

Comment: Hoq are we supposed to look at your screen?

Comment: @HerrSerker I posted a screen shot of my screen

Comment: @user3494047 But we cannot play with the code you have.

Comment: @HerrSerker I just edited my question so my code includes an entire html document. When I open that document in my browser the button is as it is in the pictures

Comment: actually when I try and remove Julio's suggestion and open in my browser, the button is small. So there must be something else in my code making the button's large :/ I guess I need to figure out what.

Answer (score 3):

Set the class `col-xs-1` to the select element and `col-xs-11` to input.

Code:

```
<div>
    <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
    <div class="container-small">
        <select class="col-xs-1" name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in selectOptions" ng-change="change(data.singleSelect)">
        </select>
        <input value="back" ng-click="upOneLevel()" class="btn btn-default col-xs-11" type="button">
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/DfPLcL7GKv

Comment: That made the button width go all the way to the edge of the screen. I'll post the screen shot.

Comment: @user3494047 you can change the classes with the number that you want. See this http://www.bootply.com/0vRM8ailou with col-xs-6 the button goes to half of window